# Searching for multiple line breaks in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find, find-and-replace

I have a large text file that I am editing in Notepad++ and want to search for all instances where there are two line breaks and a particular string of characters on the following line (i.e., two left square brackets). I managed to figure out how to search for a single line break but was unable to get this search to work with the additional line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, `\r\n` represents newlines. So, to search for two newlines followed by a "[[", turn on "`extended`" search, and search for "`\r\n\r\n[[`", exactly as I have written it. [image]

If you're on linux, you should search for `\n\n[[` instead.

Note: Ensure that "Match whole word only" is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks so much - this is timely and exactly what I wanted! :)